# "Text size" or "font size"?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

The "font" term is frequently used in "font family" meaning.
Like: - "Which font?" - "Arial".

But the "font size" definitely does not mean "the size of font family" - it refers to the size of capital letters. If it is correct, the question is "What is the font and how is it different from the text"?

### What I need to do to answer this question

Fill the below list/table with the correct terms.

- Root element

  - Text

    - Font family: Arial
    - Size: 14px
    - Line spacing: 4px
- Label element

  - Text

    - Font family: Arial
    - Size: 14px
    - Line spacing: 4px

Currently, I have "Root element > text > font family" and "Root element > text > size" hierarchy.
Is it O'K instead of  "Root element > font > family" and "Root element > font > size"?

Comment: I can't see any difference if in both cases you're talking about text in a particular font with  a particular size. (There may be pedants who disagree, but in practical usage, both "font size" and "text size" are very common.) How you put it in a table depends on your needs. In some contexts "text size" may be considered to mean the number of words or characters in the text, or the size of a text box, but here it seems clear, particularly if the units are pixels or points.

Comment: It's unclear whether you consider the size to be a property of the font or not. If you're asking whether people generally do or not, then you should indicate what research you've done (there is plenty of information about this issue available from various sources) and why that research didn't help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really about English. "Font" and "text" are terms from the jargon of graphic design, and are not governed by any rules of English.

Comment: fonts are measured in **points**, look at your Word program. Text size and font size are not the same thing at all. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography) In digital type, letters of a font are designed around an imaginary space called an em square. **When a point size of a font is specified, the font is scaled so that its em square has a side length of that particular length in points**

Comment: This is about the etymology of technical terms for methods, hardware and software for producing type/text. Today, for all practical purposes, "type size" and "font size" are interchangeable. So is "typeface" and "font". People don't know the (historical) differences. It's a good idea to use the terms "font-family" and "type-size". Experienced designers know that text specs almost always include font (typeface), size (AKA "point size"), width (column measure), justified/ragged setting, leading (line spacing), before/after spacing, first line indent/outdent, and tracking or letterspacing.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, "text size" and "font size" mean the same thing. In some contexts, someone might understand "text size" to mean the number of characters or words rather than the size of each printed character. Like if someone said to me, "This document has a text size of 4000 characters" that wouldn't seem jarring. Font size is pretty unambiguous.

It's possible that professional printers have more precise definitions of these terms. Professionals in a field often have more precise definitions for words than the common usage. Like if I said, "Sally's biggest asset is her cheerful disposition", I am clearly using "asset" in a much more general sense than a professional accountant would use the word.